# Flash fancybox popup hiding behind other Flash element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I have a webpage I've made with some interactive flash content on it, and there is also a popup which I'm using Fancybox for.

The popup contains other flash content (a video) and in the browser when I click to view the video, it hides behind the flash content.

How can I resolve this? X-indexs or any type of parameters in the flash embed code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to do the following:

Add the following parameter to the OBJECT tag:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Add the following parameter to the EMBED tag:

```
wmode="transparent"
```

Instead of transparent you can use "opaque" too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tim make sure that the document validates with XHTML strict