# Flash object appears over jQuery Fancybox in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, fancybox

I am usng osCommerce latest version, I am using the [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) jQuery plugin for product images. In IE9 when we click an image, the jQuery lightbox appears. In my website header I am using a flash animation, The problem is that the flash animation appears front of the jQuery light box in IE9. In other browsers, it's working well. Please help me fix this.
Please see the image: http://i46.tinypic.com/2gujmnc.png

Comment: Link is dead...
Use [Fancybox 2](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox) instead.

Comment: @Mooseman Please try this link http://i46.tinypic.com/2gujmnc.png

Comment: Define the `z-index` of the flash element (e.g., `z-index: 1`) and raise the `z-index` in the fancybox config file. (e.g., `z-index: 99999`)

Comment: Try `wmode="opaque"` as one answer stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `wmode="opaque"` to your flash objects in the background.

Check for reference https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fancybox/h-tbFd1M-QE or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780766/1055987

Also make sure you have a proper `DOCTYPE` and it is the very first line of your html document.

Comment: This has worked for me in the past too with navigation menus going behind flash movies, forgot about `wmode`. +1