# Fancybox and Flash overlay issue

Tags: flash, fancybox

I've an old site with an header in flash. I implemented fancybox and when i click on a image, the flash header overlay fancybox

this is the code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="900" height="200">
      <param name="movie" value="header.swf" />
      <param name="SCALE" value="noborder" /> 
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />      
      <embed src="header.swf" wmode="transparent" width="900" height="200" scale="noborder" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ></embed>
</object>
```

How can i resolve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Google 'flash is on top of other stuff html' first google result is from adobe explaining how to solve this...

Comment: change it to `wmode="opaque"` ... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14285196/1055987

Comment: I resolved with swfobject 2.2, thanks guys for the fast reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with swfobject 2.2

Thanks guys